# How to update profile table on user registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have two tables: one for `User` and one for `Profile`.
I'm trying to figure out how to update the profile table upon a user registering.

Here's my `User` and `Profile` Model classes:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;


class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{




    protected $fillable = array('fname','lname','email','password','create_at','updated_at');

    /**
    * The database table used by the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
    * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
    * Get the unique identifier for the user.
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
    * Get the password for the user.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
    * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
    * @method to insert values into database.
    */
    public static function create_user($data = array())
    {
        return User::create($data);
    }

    /**
    *@method to validate a user in the database
    */
    public static function validate_creds($data)
    {
        return Auth::attempt($data);
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Profile');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

}
```

And my profile model:

```
<?php


class Profile extends Eloquent{




    public static function createNewProfile($data)
    {
        return Profile::create($data);
    }

    public static function editProfile()
    {
        //
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try events:
http://laravel.com/docs/events

Make a On.user.create event
and build a listener that does the things you need.

I'm not sure, but you could try to put that code that updates the Profile in the User Constructor.

Comment: So you have to create an event every time you have a relationship between tables?